# GridView does not behave correctly

Tags: java, android, gridview

I have the following prolem:

I have a gridview that is powered by an ImageAdapter which downloads images from the internet and provides them to the GridView. This is working great, however there is one issue that is freaking me out. The problem is that the first 10 images that are supposed to fill the screen are loaded correctly. The 11th though is shown blank and for some unknown reason seems to be taken from convertView directly. Image 12 is displayed correctly and all the images below are blank even though they have valid URLs to be downloaded from.

This is my ImageAdapter

```
package com.wm.grid;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   private Context mContext;
   public String[] mThumbIds;
   public Bitmap[] bmp;
   public Bitmap bitmapPlaceholder;
    public ImageAdapter(Context c,String[] m) {
        mContext = c;
        mThumbIds = m;
        initBitmapListWithPlaceholders();
    }
    public void initBitmapListWithPlaceholders(){
        int count = mThumbIds.length;
        bmp = new Bitmap[count];
        for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
             bmp[i]=bitmapPlaceholder;
        }
    }
    public int getCount() {     
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.v("POSITION","P"+position+convertView);
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(210, 150));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
            Bitmap bm = getBitmap(setURL(mThumbIds[position]),position);
            bmp[position] = bm;
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);


        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp[position]);
        }
        //imageView.setImageBitmap(getBitmap(setURL(mThumbIds[position])));
        //imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }
    private URL setURL (String urls){
       try{
           URL urli = new URL(urls);
           return urli;
       }
       catch (MalformedURLException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    return null;
    }
    private Bitmap getBitmap (URL url,int position){

       try{
           Log.v("POSITION","Loading "+position+url);
           Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) url.getContent());
           return bm;
       }
  catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
    return null;
    }
 /*   public Integer[] AddItems(Integer[] a){
        final Integer[] aThumbIds;
        final int i;
        aThumbIds = a;
        Integer[] a2 = new Integer[mThumbIds.length + aThumbIds.length];
        System.arraycopy(mThumbIds, 0, a2, 0, mThumbIds.length);
        System.arraycopy(aThumbIds, 0, a2, mThumbIds.length, aThumbIds.length);
        mThumbIds = a2;
        return mThumbIds;
    }
    */
}
```

The GridActivity.java is not provided because it only has an array of strings(links) that are passed to the Adapter.

main.xml is only a gridview so I dont think it is anything to do with.

What is more I have output of some debug points and it is very strange.

```
11-10 14:55:28.700: V/POSITION(12936): Loading 0 //Loading the first image
11-10 14:55:28.785: V/POSITION(12936): P0android.widget.ImageView@40536450//First image found in ConvertView (why ? it is already loaded ... :()
11-10 14:55:28.790: V/POSITION(12936): P0android.widget.ImageView@40536450//Same thing
11-10 14:55:28.790: V/POSITION(12936): P1null//All OK convertView is null load image from web
11-10 14:55:28.790: V/POSITION(12936): Loading 1
11-10 14:55:28.895: V/POSITION(12936): P2null
11-10 14:55:28.895: V/POSITION(12936): Loading 2
11-10 14:55:29.070: V/POSITION(12936): P3null
11-10 14:55:29.070: V/POSITION(12936): Loading 3
11-10 14:55:29.175: V/POSITION(12936): P4null
11-10 14:55:29.175: V/POSITION(12936): Loading 4
11-10 14:55:29.290: V/POSITION(12936): P5null
11-10 14:55:29.290: V/POSITION(12936): Loading 5
11-10 14:55:29.420: V/POSITION(12936): P6null
11-10 14:55:29.420: V/POSITION(12936): Loading 6
11-10 14:55:29.500: V/POSITION(12936): P7null
11-10 14:55:29.505: V/POSITION(12936): Loading 7
11-10 14:55:29.580: V/POSITION(12936): P8null
11-10 14:55:29.580: V/POSITION(12936): Loading 8
11-10 14:55:29.675: V/POSITION(12936): P9null
11-10 14:55:29.675: V/POSITION(12936): Loading 9
11-10 14:55:29.800: V/POSITION(12936): P0null//again !? P0 was loaded in first place why does it try to load it again ?!... and it is even NULL ?!
11-10 14:55:29.800: V/POSITION(12936): Loading 0
11-10 14:55:29.910: V/POSITION(12936): P0android.widget.ImageView@40547ea0
=====================
11-10 15:02:00.435: V/POSITION(12936): P10android.widget.ImageView@40547ea0//Now image 10 was NEVER loaded before why the heck it is in the convertView !?
11-10 15:02:00.435: V/POSITION(12936): P11null//Image 11 is loaded correctly.
11-10 15:02:00.435: V/POSITION(12936): Loading 11
=====================(Scrolling down is even more questionable)
11-10 15:03:10.740: V/POSITION(12936): P12android.widget.ImageView@405505f0//Where the heck convertView found this image (never loaded)
11-10 15:03:10.740: V/POSITION(12936): P13android.widget.ImageView@40536450//Same applies for this one.
```

The result of the above is that images 10 12 and 13 and all images below are blank

Any clues are welcomed. Thank you very much in advance.

EDIT: One more thing. If I alter the code like this:

```
if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(210, 150));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
            Bitmap bm = getBitmap(setURL(mThumbIds[position]),position);
            bmp[position] = bm;
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);


        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            imageView.setImageBitmap(getBitmap(setURL(mThumbIds[position]),position));//DOWNLOAD IMAGE AGAIN
        }
```

The images are displayed correctly however the application is working two slow because it is always downloading the image.

Answer (score 0):

try to implement cache in your project here is [link](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)